# How do i fix this program in python?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with a program; I need to find out how to add all the numbers in the input

```
w = 0
v = str(w)
x = input('Enter the expenses: ')
y = x.split()
for x in y:
    v = v + x
print(v)
```

I need to figure out how to add multiple numbers in the input as a example

> Enter the expenses: 10 2 5 15

and it should be 32.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert everything to a numerical type, e.g. int. You are currently adding strings:

```
v = 0
x = input('Enter the expenses: ')
y = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
for x in y:
    v = v + x
print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `v` and `x` are string, so you are doing string concatenation here, rather than numeric addition.

```
w = 0
v = str(w)
x = raw_input('Enter the expenses: ')
y = x.split()
for x in y:
    v = v + x
print(v)
```

Output:

```
Enter the expenses: 10 20 30 40
010203040
```

Make item `int`  first.

I would solve it this way, using `map` and `sum`:

```
str_input=raw_input('Enter the expenses: ')
lst=str_input.split()
print sum(map(int,lst))
```

You can't simply concatenate them with `+` sign. Use `format`,like below:

```
print "${0}".format(sum(map(int,lst)))
```

Comment: thanks  but how do i print it so it has a doller sign before the sum of the numbers